# Can't install the 12.2.2.1 JDeveloper.jar on Mac

Tags: macos, jar, jdeveloper

I can't open the JDeveloper.jar on Mac(10.11.4  JDK 1.8.0_73)

double-click the file , it show can't open ( check the console ).

//The only info I can find (I'm not sure it's the right one , because when I open the console and click again , nothing changed on consolo.
16/3/30 20:54:38.180 lsd[233]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist

Then I install use java -jar to open .. It give me the message:
1.lack needed jar file 
2.can't extract /private/var/folders/3w/ly610lmd5nbcqjs6bk57pq1r0000gn/T/orcl1921397507371152795.tmp

BTW:I can use java -jar to open the JDeveloper 1213.

THX

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the two files that make up the install.
Then in the directory where they both are issue a :
java -jar thefirstfile.jar